# How to find out the iframe structure of FirefoxOS?

Tags: iframe, firefox-os, firefox-marionette

I would like to use marionette to test my Firefox OS application, but I need to know the iframe structure of the phone to be able to switch frames.
I found a couple of tutorials, but I think they work only for older versions (I have B2G 2.2).

So my question is, **how I could find out the iframe structure?**

I would appreciate any *example to test a custom app with marionette, using FFOS with B2G 2.2*.

Every debug tool I used only shows the actual app's structure (but I can not see anything outside of the app's boundaries).

Comment: Do you want to test the app directly on the phone or in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

According to the tutorial [Part 2: Basic interactions with Firefox OS using Marionette](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/Automated_testing/gaia-ui-tests/Part_2_Marionette_Firefox_OS_interactions), after connecting

```
from marionette import Marionette
marionette = Marionette()
marionette.start_session()
```

You should then be able to use

```
marionette.find_elements('css selector', 'iframe')
```

to get a list of all the iframes in the page. This matches [Part 2: UI Testing on Firefox OS. Working with iframes](https://blog.mozilla.org/webqa/2013/02/13/part-2-ui-testing-on-firefox-os-working-with-iframes/).

Apart from that, after connecting to the app, you can request [`marionette.page_source`](http://marionette-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html) which should yield all of the page (as a very long string).